# In a Python list, why are my appended values not the same values I appended?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a mat that looks like this:

```
mat = [ [0,0,0,0], [6,7,8,9] ]
```

I want a list of mats that looks like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Here's the code I used:

```
# 2D List with some values
mat = [ [0,0,0,0], [6,7,8,9] ]

# append to listOfMats new a modified mat
# prints what I want listOfMats to look like
print("What listOfMats should look like:")
listOfMats = []
for x in range(4):
    mat[0][x] = 1
    print(mat)
    listOfMats.append(mat.copy())
    mat[0][x] = 0
print()

print("What I get for listOfMats: ")
for i in listOfMats:
    print(i)
```

Here's the output:

```
What listOfMats should look like:
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

What I get for listOfMats: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I think the problem is in this line:

```
mat[0][x] = 1
print(mat)
listOfMats.append(mat.copy())
mat[0][x] = 0
```

mat[0][x] is changed to 1, then I append a deep copy of that mat into listOfMats. But somehow, that appended deep copy is changed with mat[0][x] = 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mat.copy()` is a *shallow copy*. The inner lists are not themselves copies. You need something like `[row.copy() for row in mat]`

Comment: `list(map(list.copy, mat))`

Comment: @JohnColeman, ah thanks for that! I learned something today about matrices and deep copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of John is correct. We need a deep copy of the list here.

A way to do that that works with any kind of lists is to use the `copy` library:

```py
import copy

mat_copy = copy.deepcopy(mat)
```

Your full code:

```py
import copy

# 2D List with some values
mat = [ [0,0,0,0], [6,7,8,9] ]

# append to listOfMats new a modified mat
# prints what I want listOfMats to look like
print("What listOfMats should look like:")
listOfMats = []
for x in range(4):
    mat[0][x] = 1
    print(mat)
    listOfMats.append(copy.deepcopy(mat))
    mat[0][x] = 0
print()

print("What I get for listOfMats: ")
for i in listOfMats:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, when you call `copy` on an array in python, a new *reference* to that array is created. This means that at any given time, there is only 1 instance of this array and a bunch of references or *handles* pointing to that instance. This is called a *shallow* copy.

So, in your code, when you do this:

```py
for x in range(4):
    mat[0][x] = 1    # Here you modify the original
    print(mat)
    listOfMats.append(mat.copy())
    mat[0][x] = 0    # Here you un-modify the original
```

You effectively undo your modification of setting a specific "1" right after you make the `copy()`. Doing that, changes what all the references are pointing to as well. What you really want is to make a *deep* copy. And to do that all you need to change is:

`listOfMats.append(mat.copy())` to `listOfMats.append(mat.deepcopy())`.

Comment: `list` [doesn't have](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) a `deepcopy` member function.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. As @TQA answered above, you need to `import copy` and then use `copy.deepcopy(...)`.